# How to launch the ViewContent facebook event in React Native?

Tags: facebook, react-native, facebook-sdk-4.0

I'm trying to trigger the **ViewContent** event (https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-pixel/reference#events) using the version **0.10.1** of **react-native-fbsdk**. This should be registered in the panel you see in the image, but it still appears in red.

[image]

The only function the SDK gives me to launch events is the **logEvent** function. So I'm doing it this way:

```
 const viewContentData = {
    content_name: name,
    content_category: type,
    content_ids: id,
    content_type: type,
    value: amount,
    currency,
  };

  yield call([AppEventsLogger, 'logEvent'], 'ViewContent', viewContentData);
```

Does anyone know how to make it work?

Thank you so much :)

Answer (score 0):

Do you try to use it on Web or Mobile? I believe for react native you have to use mobile events SDK integration:
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/react-native/app-events

If you want to use it on the Web, all you have to do is initializing the pixel base code properly and then firing the event via `fbq` helper function:
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-pixel/advanced/

Comment: I'm trying to use it on mobile. The documentation says that I just could use the logEvent function. Any idea?

Comment: The call seems to be OK actually, accept I'm not really sure why do you have a generator function. Do you use React Native for iOS as well? There you see the events coming through.

Comment: When debugging WEB and Mobile, I would usually first start by sending very simple events with minimum extra data to see they are coming through and logged by FB nicely.  Did you succeed to send it without any parameters? Like sending a `PageView` with this signature `logEvent(eventName: string);`

The other way around it is using smth like [Charles](https://www.charlesproxy.com/) to see if anything is being event sent from your App.

Comment: I would also check if the App is linked to Add account correctly and all the IDs are where they should be. Could this be helpful maybe: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/app-events/getting-started-app-events-android